# mergedModelFromBundles initial retain count?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Or in other words why would I need to retain the object returned by `[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles]`. Is there any memory menagement rule explicitly guiding me to retain it? I assume the retain count is 0 on return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't own the object returned to you because you didn't create it.  If you want to keep it around (take ownership) beyond the current scope then you need to retain it.  The [rules are here.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1)